# Setting CodeMirror value with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codemirror

I have a page where I included CodeMirror:

```
var editor = CodeMirror(function(node){ce.parentNode.replaceChild(node, ce);}, {
    autorefresh: true,
    value: "",
});
```

With ajax I ran this script:

```
editor.setValue('abc');
```

Nothing updates. Is there a way to set the value of a CodeMirror instance with an ajax request?

Comment: Can you show us the AJAX request? Are you sure `editor.setValue('abc');` is executed?

Comment: I am making that ajax request via rails, but I have some script along with it that gets executed. I am sure it is.